# Spread multiple columns with values by one columne containing key

Tags: r, tidyr

Input data :

```
> head(iris[c(48:50, 98:100), 3:5])
    Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
48           1.4         0.2     setosa
49           1.5         0.2     setosa
50           1.4         0.2     setosa
98           4.3         1.3 versicolor
99           3.0         1.1 versicolor
100          4.1         1.3 versicolor
```

Output data :

```
setosa.Petal.Length versicolor.Petal.Length setosa.Petal.Width versicolor.Petal.Width 
1.4                 4.3                     0.2                1.3
1.5                 3.0                     0.2                1.1
1.4                 4.1                     0.2                1.3
```

using for example :

```
spread(
  iris%>%mutate(n=row_number()), 
  key=Species, 
  value=Petal.Length:Petal.Width) 
  #or c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")`
```

doesn't work

Comment: Could do something like `df %>% gather(key, value, -Species) %>% unite(tmp, Species, key) %>% group_by(tmp) %>% mutate(indx = row_number()) %>% spread(tmp, value)` perhaps

Comment: @David Arenburg but your code produce vector of length of `numberOfColumns*numberOfRows`, so for large datasets there will be problem

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your concern. Speed or memory usage? If speed, simply don't use tidyverse, and try something like `library(data.table) ; dcast(melt(setDT(df), "Species"), rowid(Species, variable) ~ Species + variable)` instead. If memory usage, then you will probably need use some unvectorized approach (such as `lapply`) in order to run operations in chinks.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this and was curious about the mention on "large datasets". As an avid fan of everything tidyverse I am oftern benchmarking performace as I work with large sets constantly. For this example this is what I came up with, which was alarmingly in the favor of using base package functions over piping with tidyverse calls.

#### For these purposes using a split and base functions is alarmingly faster than piping. Anyone have any feedback on this ???

Replicating the iris data set to fake a larger data set.

```
iris_1000 <- plyr::ldply(1:1000, function(i){
  iris
})
```

Dimensions are 150,000 rows by 5 columns:

```
dim(iris_1000)
[1] 150000      5
```

So this would represent a dataset with a size of:

```
sprintf("%s MB", object.size(iris_1000) * 0.001^2)
[1] "5.401688 MB"
```

Wrapping the provided anser in a function call for testing but changing so that it applies to all columns, not just those containing 'Petal' and also dropping the index column and returning as a data frame

```
tidy_fn <- function(){
  iris_1000 %>% 
    gather(key, value, -Species) %>%
    unite(tmp, Species, key, sep=".") %>%
    group_by(tmp) %>%
    mutate(indx = row_number()) %>%
    spread(tmp, value) %>% 
    select(-indx) %>% data.frame
}
```

Function using mostly base package provided functions and taking an input
of data frame as the 'df' variable and the column name that the data is to be 
aggregated by, or in our case split on

```
baseish_fn <- function(df, col_split){

  df_split <- split(df, df[[col_split]])

  df_loop <- lapply(names(df_split), function(i){
    iter_df <- df_split[[i]][-which(colnames(df_split[[i]]) == col_split)]
    new_names <- sprintf("%s.%s", i, colnames(iter_df))
    colnames(iter_df) <- new_names
    iter_df
  })
  names(df_loop) <- NULL
  as.data.frame(df_loop)
}
```

Now the speed comparisons were surprising...
 One note is that the column names in the baseish function will be arranged to 
 match the returned col arrangement of the tudy function for later comparison
 of values so run once to get that

```
tidy_val_test <- tidy_fn()

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  tidyverse = tidy_fn(),
  `base-ish` = baseish_fn(iris_1000, "Species")[colnames(tidy_val_test)],times = 100L
)

Unit: milliseconds                                                       
      expr       min        lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
 tidyverse 378.46753 419.93116 447.8020 438.5375 466.78367 718.9666   100
  base-ish  76.57918  83.21915  92.8109  87.8329  94.58085 342.2290   100
```

And to ensure they produced identical outputs:

```
all(mapply(function(i){
    identical(tidyverse[[i]], `base-ish`[[i]])
},colnames(tidyverse)))

[1] TRUE


head(`base-ish`[1:4,1:5])
  setosa.Sepal.Length setosa.Sepal.Width setosa.Petal.Length setosa.Petal.Width
1                 5.1                3.5                 1.4                0.2
2                 4.9                3.0                 1.4                0.2
3                 4.7                3.2                 1.3                0.2
4                 4.6                3.1                 1.5                0.2
  versicolor.Sepal.Length
1                     7.0
2                     6.4
3                     6.9
4                     5.5
```

Comment: I'm not sure if OP was concerned regarding performance or memory usage. I was under the impression of the latter. And if you work with large data sets then you should not be surprise that tidyverse is slow. This is long time known fact. tidyverse agenda is "easy syntax" on the expanse of performance. If speed is a concern, I would simply go with `library(data.table) ; dcast(melt(setDT(df), "Species"), rowid(Species, variable) ~ Species + variable)`

Answer (score 0):

I was writing my answer until I saw [David Arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg) great comment, and I adapted my answer with his.

I got this:

```
df <- iris %>%
  select(c(starts_with("Petal"), Species)) %>%
  gather(key, value, -Species) %>%
  unite(tmp, Species, key, sep=".") %>%
  group_by(tmp) %>%
  mutate(indx = row_number()) %>%
  spread(tmp, value)
```

I didn't know the `unite()` function, that was the main difference.

---

Obs: Since I can't comment I needed to post as an answer, and I can erase this if you feel like I'm stealing your answer.